# jQuery | detach(), append() scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **main-div** and two divs with the class of **container**. The div with the class of **container** has a child div with a class of **content** with different contents. I'd like for the user to click on their choice of containers and transport its content to **main-div**. Then when the user clicks on the **main-div**, I'd like to transport that content back to its original div.

I'm not sure how to detach the content from main-div once it's been passed and reinsert it back into its original parent. I would appreciate any help.

I can't use IDs. I can only uses classes.

HTML

```
<div class="main-div">
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="contents">
  A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="contents">
  B
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-div {
  width: 100wv;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contents {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

JS

```
  $('.container').click(function() {
    var child = $(this).children();
    console.log('child ' + child);
    $('.main-div').append(child);
  });

  $('.main-div').click(function(child) {
    console.log('child ' + child);
    $('.main-div').detach(child);
  });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4vct1hv0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Set ids for the containers

```
<div class="main-div">
</div>


<div class="container" id="container1">
  <div class="contents">
    A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="container2">
  <div class="contents">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

And set a data attribute for the children on click to identify the parent element.

```
$(function() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    var child = $(this).children();
    child.attr("data-parentcontainer", this.id);
    $('.main-div').append(child);
  });

  $('.main-div').click(function(child) {
    var child = $(this).children();
    child.appendTo($("#" + child.data("parentcontainer")));
  });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7cxwmhod/)**

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can't use IDs it needs to be only class based.

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS snippet and let me know if it helps

```js
  $('.container').click(function() {
  console.log('foo');
    var child = $(this).html();
    console.log(child);
    $('.main-div').append(child);
  });
  
  $('.main-div').click(function() {
  console.log('foo');
    var main = $(this).html();
    if(main.length != 0) {
     $('.main-div').empty();
    }
    else
     console.log('Main div is empty');
  });
```

Comment: this helps a lot, but I'm looking to specifically detach the div that was added not empty the div.

Comment: The above snippet detaches the div nevertheless, mate. It removes it from the DOM. That is what you mean when you say detach, right?

Answer (score 0):

**[External DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4vct1hv0/5/)**

You can use `.detach()` and `.appendTo()`, but along with that you have to keep some identification to know from that `.contents` div was picked up. So I am making use of `data-address` attribute for the parent of picked `.contents` so as to attach it back there. See inline comments for detailed explanation on what will happen with the code.

```js
$('.main-div').on('click', function(e) {
  var elem = $(e.target); //capture click event on .main-div
  if (elem.hasClass('contents')) { //check if click was on .contents div
    var text = elem.text().trim(); //if yes then get its text
    elem.detach();//detach the element
    elem.appendTo($('div[data-address=' + text + ']')); //attach it based on attribute selector of jquery
  }
});
$('.contents').on('click', function() {
  var elem = $(this);//get the element
  elem.closest('.container').attr('data-address', elem.text().trim())
  //add or update data-address attribute of its closest parent i.e. .container
  elem.detach();//detach the element
  elem.appendTo($('.main-div')); //append it to .main-div
})
```

```css
.main-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.contents {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="contents">
    A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="contents">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some uniqueness on the div that have class container, you can add a class or id so that when reinserting back to the original div we can identify the div.

i don't think is there other solution to reinsert back to the original div, whenever we identify both div uniquely.

please change your html structure so that we can manipulate through jquery.